# Crashing app when cancelling taking picture within the camera is processing the image shot

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

There is a scenario, when I try to take a picture on a device and I press the "shutter" button and right after that I press cancel (dismiss) – as a result, I get error that I can't track. It says:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18271c2d8 0x193f400e4 0x182605428 0x18df304e8 0x18df30188 0x18df7d728 0x18df7dd28 0x188ef111c 0x188ef08a4 0x100f80fd4 0x100f80f94 0x100f85c28 0x1826d37f8 0x1826d18a0 0x1825fd2d4 0x18be136fc 0x1871c2fac 0x1002c35c0 0x1945bea08)
```

More information about the context:

I have iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3
I'm using the UIImagePickerController it crashes before calling the "imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:" method.
I have custom overlay with cancel button, which calls method to dismiss the UIImagePickerController.

Is this a common bug of the iOS or do I have something wrong?
Could it be because I use custom overlay with the custom cancel button?

Comment: Why don't you just disable the cancel button until the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method is called?

Comment: Sudeep: Cool, didn't think about that. It's true I can disable the cancel button when pressing the "shutter" button. On the other hand I would prefer some reasonable explanation why this happens.

Comment: I have same crash without custom cancel button (on 8.1.1, 8.4, 8.4.1). But I can't reproduce it, I've seen it in crashLogs. Do you find a solution?

Comment: any solution for this ? I am facing same issue without cancel button. app just crash some time after taking pic. but I am not able to reproduce it.